# Customization of SharePoint links

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, hyperlink, links-list

Just got done creating a master page from a customized design and I'm trying to find a way to strip off SharePoint's own `CSS` from the navigation links and use mine, but to no avail.

I'd also like to strip off the `spans` that wraps the `links` and leave just the `li`

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: the Quick Launch Navigation or the Global?

Comment: @Colbs it say Top Navigation. I'm pretty new to sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about stripping off the `span`s, but you can override the default styles by using an Alternate CSS file.  You create a CSS file that targets the elements you want to style, so for targeting navigation elements you might use selectors like

```
#DeltaTopNavigation a.ms-navedit-linkNode {
    /* for links in the top nav bar */
}

#sideNavBox .root li {
    /* for li's in the quicklaunch */
}
```

for example.  There are many classes and elements you can use to select exactly what you want to style.  Then you define your overriding styles and upload the style sheet to somewhere in the site, like Site Assets or the Style Library.  Then go to Site Settings, and under the "Look and Feel" section, click on the Master Page link, and you should see a section where you can specify the URL to the Alternate CSS file.  You can find a lot of articles out there on the web detailing how to do this, and [here's one](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/upload-an-alternate-style-sheet-in-sharepoint-2010.html).

Alternatively, if you are not using the Publishing features and the Master Page link in site settings is not available to you, since you are defining your own custom master page, you can just link to the custom CSS file from within the master page.